# Using Jackson with multiple Enumerators

Tags: java, json, scala, jackson

So I have two classes that extend scala.Enumeration, and I'm running into a jackson issue where it can't tell which serializer to use. Has anyone found a solution to this issue?

here are the two classes:

class 1:

```
object status1 extends Enumeration{
  type status1 = Value
  val OK, OK_BACKFETCH, MISSING, UNKNOWN = Value
}
```

class 2:

```
object DataPointStatus extends Enumeration {
  type DataPointStatus = Value
  val OK, OK_BARRIER, MISSING, MISSING_BARRIER, NO_DATA, UNKNOWN = Value
}
```

serializer 1:

```
class class1Serializer extends CustomSerializer[class1](format => (
    {
      case status: JString=>
        status match {
          case JString("ok") => class1.OK
          case JString("backfetch") => class1.OK_BACKFETCH
          case JString("missing") => class1.MISSING
          case _ => class1.UNKNOWN
        }
    },
    {
      case status: class1 =>
        status match {
          case class1.OK => JString("ok")
          case class1.OK_BACKFETCH => JString("backfetch")
          case class1.MISSING => JString("missing")
          case _ => JString("unknown")
        }
    }
    ))
```

(serializer 2 looks basically the same)

Comment: Have you thought of using case objects instead of Enumeration? I think it might simplify the serialization issue.

Comment: Is it jackson or json4s? What is full class name for CustomSerializer?